# Creating XML requests and sending them to server using ASIHttpRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, libxml2

I am trying to generate XML request to be sent to server over Http Post. I am aware of ASIHttpRequest library and want to use it.

I have two questions regarding this:
1) How to generate XML request? (Which is best library to use? GData/libXML/KissXML? or else?)
2) How to send it to server using ASIHttpRequest?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved it this way:

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postBody
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"r" forKey:newStr];
request.delegate = self;
[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is postBody in this case? I have a XML request which I want to post to a server